# PHP simple xml loop

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Hi I have an xml file like that

```
<param typ="bool" nazwa="balkon">true</param>

<param typ="bool" nazwa="lazienka_wc">true</param>

<param typ="int" nazwa="liczbapieter">5</param>

<param typ="int" nazwa="liczbapokoi">3</param>

<param typ="int" nazwa="liczbalazienek">1</param>
```

I am looping through this like that:

```
            foreach($oferta->param as $p){
                print_r($p->attributes()->nazwa);
            }
```

I print out nazwa attr for every param but how can i get values: true, true, 5, 3, 1?

Comment: Try changing `print_r($p->attributes()->nazwa);` to `echo $p` and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
$xml = <<<XML
   <root>
       <param typ="bool" nazwa="balkon">true</param>
       <param typ="bool" nazwa="lazienka_wc">true</param>
       <param typ="int" nazwa="liczbapieter">5</param>
       <param typ="int" nazwa="liczbapokoi">3</param>
       <param typ="int" nazwa="liczbalazienek">1</param>
    </root>
XML;
$oferta = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$values = [];
foreach($oferta->param as $p){
    $values[] = $p;
}
error_log('values: '.implode(', ',$values));
```

Which outputs in my error log file:

```
values: true, true, 5, 3, 1
```

Comment: I've tried but i get something like:
{
0: "true",
@attributes: {
nazwa: "lazienka_wc",
typ: "bool"
}
},
if I do $p[0]; it dont show anything

Comment: @SzymonMudrak I have edited my answer. How does it differ to your setup?
Also is there a specific format that you want it to be?

Answer (score 0):

To get the *string content* of a SimpleXMLElement, you [cast it to a string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting):

```
$example = simplexml_load_string('<foo>Hello</foo>');
$content = (string)$example;
var_dump($content); // string(5) "Hello"
```

So in your case, you want to cast `$p` to string in the loop:

```
foreach($oferta->param as $p){
    $value = (string)$p;
}
```

Also, there is a short-hand for `$p->attributes()->nazwa`, which is `$p['nazwa']`. With either syntax, that also returns an object, so you probably want to cast that to a string as well:

```
foreach($oferta->param as $p){
    $value = (string)$p;
    $nazwa = (string)$p['nazwa'];
}
```